# Unity: AudioClip sounds disappear after loading

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I created a scenario where there are different sound clips if the player crashes or lands on a landing pad successfully. The problem is when the player and and falls over a second later, both audioClips play and the next scene loads, but the audioClips I placed in the inspector variables disappear and I get a null error. How do I fix that?

The code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class CollisionHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    AudioSource audioSource;

    [HideInInspector] public int currentSceneIndex;
    [SerializeField] private float delaySec = 1.5f;
    //controls crash sound and volume
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip crashSound;
    [SerializeField] private float crashVol = 0.1f;
    //victory sound and volume
    [SerializeField] private AudioClip victorySound;
    [SerializeField] private float victoryVol = 0.8f;


    void Start() {
        if (audioSource == null) audioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        if (audioSource == null) {
            audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        }
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other) 
    {
        switch (other.gameObject.tag) // checks the collided object's tag
        {
            case "Friendly":
                Debug.Log("Safe!");
                break;
            case "Finish":
                Debug.Log("Finished!");
                StartSuccess();
                break;
            case "Boost":
                Debug.Log("Boost!");
                break;
            case "Boundary":
                Debug.Log("Wall!");
                break;
            default:
                Debug.Log("Hit!");
                startCrash(); 
                break;
        }
    }

    private void StartSuccess()
    {
        // add SFX and particles
        if (victorySound != null) {
            audioSource.clip = victorySound;
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(victorySound, victoryVol); // plays the sound and volume from the audioSource component
        }
        GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
        Invoke(nameof(loadLevel), delaySec);
    }

    private void startCrash() {

        // add SFX and particles
        if (victorySound != null) {
            audioSource.clip = crashSound;
            audioSource.PlayOneShot(crashSound, crashVol); // plays the sound and volume from the audioSource component
        }
        GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false; //disables player movement script
        Invoke(nameof(ReloadLevel), delaySec); // no longer reliant on string

    }

    
    private void loadLevel() { // returns the currently active scene + its index, then loads.
        Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        currentSceneIndex = scene.buildIndex;
        int nextSceneIndex = scene.buildIndex+1;
        if (nextSceneIndex == SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings) {
           nextSceneIndex = 0; // resets the index count if reaches final level
        }
         SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(nextSceneIndex); //Async is preferable, needs an index int
    }

    private void ReloadLevel() {
        currentSceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(currentSceneIndex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this issue is to make the audio source persistent between scenes. You can achieve this by using `DontDestroyOnLoad` for the object carrying the `AudioSource`.

Here's an Example of your code that manages the audio source to persist between scene loads:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

 public class CollisionHandler : MonoBehaviour
  {
    static AudioSource audioSource; // Static to persist between scenes

   [HideInInspector] public int currentSceneIndex;
   [SerializeField] private float delaySec = 1.5f;
    // controls crash sound and volume
   [SerializeField] private AudioClip crashSound;
   [SerializeField] private float crashVol = 0.1f;
   // victory sound and volume
   [SerializeField] private AudioClip victorySound;
   [SerializeField] private float victoryVol = 0.8f;

   void Awake()
    {
    if (audioSource == null)
    {
        audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        DontDestroyOnLoad(audioSource); // Makes the AudioSource persistent
    }
}

// ... (other code remains the same)

private void StartSuccess()
{
    // add SFX and particles
    if (victorySound != null && audioSource != null)
    {
        audioSource.clip = victorySound;
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(victorySound, victoryVol);
    }
    GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
    Invoke(nameof(loadLevel), delaySec);
}

private void startCrash()
{
    // add SFX and particles
    if (crashSound != null && audioSource != null)
    {
        audioSource.clip = crashSound;
        audioSource.PlayOneShot(crashSound, crashVol);
    }
    GetComponent<PlayerMovement>().enabled = false;
    Invoke(nameof(ReloadLevel), delaySec);
 }

// ... (other methods remain the same)
}
```

This adjustment should make the AudioSource persistent, so it continues to exist even after the scene changes.

- Remember to check that the clips are assigned correctly in the Inspector, and the audio source should persist as the scene changes.